# Xcode 6 cannot drag ImageView to create outlet collection

Tags: xcode, swift

I am using Xcode 6 and so far I have had nothing but problems. My most recent problem however really has baffled me. I am creating a Tic Tac Toe game and I am using 9 image view objects. I am trying to ctrl drag across from the objects to my swift file in assistant editor but when I try to drag, nothing happens. Usually that blue line would appear right where your outlet would be created when you let go of the mouse but literally nothing is happening no matter where in the file I drag it to.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this step by step.

0/ Check in your Storyboard's Identity Inspector that the `UIViewController` / `UITableViewCell` / etc that contains your `UIImageView`s has the correct class name.

1/ Add the following code in your class:

```
@IBOutlet var imageViewCollection: [AnyObject]!
```

2/ **From your class**, drag your `imageViewCollection` outlet to your `UIImageView`s. Or, **from Connections Inspector**, drag your `imageViewCollection` outlet to your `UIImageView`s (see image below).

[image]

3/ In your class, replace `AnyObject` with `UIImageView` so that your `imageViewCollection` declaration looks like the following:

```
@IBOutlet var imageViewCollection: [UIImageView]!
```

Comment: Still when I do this, where I would usually drag my image view objects over to connect them to this collection, absolutely nothing happens. Really puzzling me!

Comment: It should work if you drag from Connections Inspector. See my edit.